# Lost a comment that I made on a friend’s news feed

Tags: facebook

I finished the comment and then I posted it but didn't go in to my timeline. Now I'm trying to find it and I can't. Where do I need to go to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it posted successfully (and it hasn't been deleted) you should be able to see it in your Activity Log.

1. Click on your name to go to your profile
2. Click on "View Activity Log"

There's everything you've done on Facebook, in descending date order. You might want to filter on "Your Posts".